# phonegap-localhost not working?

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I am doveloping phonegap app using aide phonegap on android.everything fine but  localhost:8080 not working. I am load my site from localhost its not working ,in config.xml file
`<content src="http://localhost:8080/index.html" />
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>`
For Apache, mysql I am using kickweb server,in browser that link working fine.but after compile and launch the app it will close ,how do I load my site from localhost on phonegap.
Thank you

Comment: are u using the whitelist plugin in your config.xml?

Comment: Yes using,but not working. When I stop the php server it shows error and turn on it app will automatically crashed after 5 seconds.how do I fix it